# Get information about page after forwarding

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python-Selenium. After completing `form1` in `page1` I am clicking on button: "submit" then I get forward to `form2`in `page2`.

But the problem is that I don't know how can I appeal to `form2` in `page2`.
`browser.get("https://page2")` won't work.

If I use:

```
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('E:\page2.png')
```

In this screenshot I see only `form1` in `page1`.

If you need some more information just write.

Comment: Here .you need to switch window like `driver.switch_to_window(windows[1])` after clicking on `submit` button.

Comment: Im new in python, but method "switch_to_window" isn't necessary while I would get foward to page2(page1 would be still opened). In my example I have got only 1page opened in browser.

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep(x) fixed my problem.

If you know better idea, feel free to write it.